# Notation for pointwise exponentiation of a function

Tags: notation, exponentiation

There exists notation for the [pointwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise) multiplication of a function $j$ or $k$. This is often denoted as $j\cdot k$ or $j \circ k$ using the [Hadamard notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)). Consider the pointwise exponentiation of some function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ with exponent $n$ denoted by $g:Y\rightarrow Z$:

$$Z = \left\{x_i \in X|f(x_i)^{n}\right\}$$

How can the operation of pointwise exponentiation be notated? Does $g = f^n$ suffice? For instance in the programming language Matlab this operation would be expressed as
`X.^n` to distinguish it from `X^n` which denotes matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positive $n$, the notation $f^n$ usually means repeated composition as per [Wikipedia: Exponential Notation for Function Names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Exponential_notation_for_function_names).
An exception to this rule is trigonometric and logarithmic functions where the exponent always means repeated multiplication.  Thus

$$ \sin^2 x = (\sin x) (\sin x) $$
$$ \log^2 x = (\log x) (\log x) $$

I think it is ok to use $f^n$ to denote point wise exponentiation (repeated product)

$$ f^n(x) = \big(f(x) \big)^n $$

as long as you clearly define it.